# Classification of $\mathbb{G}_m$-torsors?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Is there a nice proof or reference to one of the theorem that any $\mathbb{G}_m$-torsor is isomorphic to $\mathcal{L}\setminus z(S)\to S$?

Here I am denoting by $\mathcal{L}\to S$ to be a line bundle over a scheme $S$, and $z$ to be the $0$ section.